# argmin,argmaxの使用について

Tags: julia

配列の最小、最大の要素を返すコマンドにargmin,argmaxというものがあるのですが

```
a = [10,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
argmin(a) #2
```

これは２番目の要素が最小ですという解釈で進めます。

```
argmin(a[3:5])#1
```

となるのですが、これは3~5番目の最小は３番目ですよという意味ですか？
もしそうだとするならば、３番目と表示させるためにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: あ、やはり上記の考えであっている感じですね。

Comment: 非効率ではありますが、`findmin` や `findmax` を使う方法もあります。`findmin([(a[i], i) for i=3:5])[1][2]`, `findmax([(a[i], i) for i=3:5])[1][2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
argmin(a[3:5])
```

は省略せず愚直に書くと

```
a = [10,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = a[3:5] # 3,4,5 (値)
argmin(b)  # 1     (インデックス)
```

となるはずで、省略表記から元の配列の位置を求めたいなら、自分で配列のインデックス(の差)を計算する必要があるんじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます、どうやらそのようで、表示させたい場合は差を足していく必要がありますね。